# Fetch last inserted ID form stored procedure in MySQL

Tags: mysql

**How to fetch last inserted id?**

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_insertzonemsg`

   (IN User_Id INT(10),
    IN zid INT(10),
    IN update_titles VARCHAR(50),
    IN textarea1s TEXT,
    IN filupload1s TEXT,
    IN audio1s VARCHAR(100),
    OUT out_id INT(10))
        BEGIN
        INSERT INTO zone_message_master
        **(user_id,ZoneID,update_title,textarea1,filupload1,
        audio1,LastUpdate)**
        VALUE
        **(User_Id,zid,update_titles,textarea1s,
        filupload1s,audio1s,NOW());**

SELECT **id** as **out_id**
FROM **zone_message_master** LAST_INSERT_ID();
END$$
```

I need to return last inserted ID as `out_id` form the Table `zone_message_master`?

Answer (score 50):

You need to use SET statement. For example -

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE table1(
  id INT(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  column1 VARCHAR(10),
  column2 VARCHAR(10)
);
```

Procedure's body:

```
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO table1(column1, column2) VALUES ('value1', 'value2');
  SET out_param = LAST_INSERT_ID();
END
```

Note, that ID field is not specified in INSERT statement. This value will be inserted automatically; and of course, this ID field must have AUTO_INCREMENT option.

Answer (score 16):

You can Get Last Insert ID with the help of following code:-

Just create a stored Procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `add_enquiry`(
IN EnquiryNo varchar(40),
IN OpeningDate date,
IN ClosingDate date,
IN  CreatedOn date,
OUT LID int(11)
)

BEGIN

INSERT into `enquiries` SET `enquiry_no`=EnquiryNo ,`opening_date`=OpeningDate ,`closing_date`=ClosingDate,`created_on` =CreatedOn;

SET LID = LAST_INSERT_ID();
END
```

Call on PHP:

```
$rs = $dbh->query('CALL add_enquiry("ENQ" ,"2016-08-19","2016-08-18", "2016-11-23",@LID)'); 

$rs2 = $dbh->query("SELECT @LID as id");
$row = $rs2->fetchObject();
echo $row->id;
```

Comment: The question has nothing to do with PHP nor is it tagged as such. MySQL is completely independent of PHP and your PHP code example is out of place and uneeded on this answer.