# MySQL getting 0 from pdo lastInsertID

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Like so many others, using the pdo lastInsertID() is only returning 0 for me.  I've looked at all of the helper questions that stack Overflow puts up, searched online and I've still getting a 0. I think the code is right but I clearly missed something as I still get 0 no matter what I try.

My table has an auto-incrementing id column (named 'id').  It is also the primary key for the table.  I'm using a stored procedure for the insert and so the code looks like:

```
$stmt = $pdo_write->prepare('CALL sp_Save_Requests(:formSecret,:ipAddress)');
$stmt->bindParam(':formSecret', $formSecret, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':ipAddress', $ipAddress, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$lastID = $pdo_write->lastInsertID();
```

This consistently returns 0 even though a new id is available in the table - as can be seen below in the export from phpmyadmin.

I use separate connections depending if I'm selecting or inserting/updating.  In this instance the connection object is:

```
try {
    $pdo_write = new PDO("mysql:host=$myServer;dbname=$myDB", $myRW_UID, $myRW_PW);
    $pdo_write->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING );
    $pdo_write->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
    $pdo_write->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES,TRUE );
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'RW Connection Failed: '.$e->getMessage();
    exit();
}
```

One possible issue - I do use a trigger to create and set a guid in the table but that is set to fire before the actual insert.  The dump from phpmyadmin of the table follows though the name of the real table has been changed.:

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

-- Table structure for table `tbl_test`

CREATE TABLE `tbl_test` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `guid` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `formSecret` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
--
-- Triggers `tbl_test`
--
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `tr_TestRequests_GUID` BEFORE INSERT ON `tbl_test` FOR EACH  ROW SET NEW.guid = UUID()
$$
DELIMITER ;
--
-- Indexes for table `tbl_test`
--
ALTER TABLE `tbl_test`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `guid` (`guid`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`);
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `tbl_test`
--
ALTER TABLE `tbl_test`
  MODIFY `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=44;
COMMIT;
```

I would prefer to not use a select to pull the ID if I don't have to.  But, I'm stumped and hope that someone can see what I'm missing.  Many thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Would need the source of the stored procedure as it may be the SQL inside.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13151861/fetch-last-inserted-id-form-stored-procedure-in-mysql may give some ideas.

Comment: Here's the SPROC used for the test

DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`administrator`@`%` PROCEDURE `sp_Save_Test`(IN `formSecret` VARCHAR(100), IN `ipAddress` VARCHAR(64))
    NO SQL
INSERT INTO tbl_test 
(
   formSecret,
    ipAddress
)
VALUES
(
    formSecret,
    ipAddress
)$$
DELIMITER ;

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had a syntax error in the id assignment to the out variable. Took forever to see it but it works now.

Thanks for the feedback and making me go back through this once again.